# Programa parando de responder em C - lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade em C e praticamente já terminei o mesmo. Entretanto, enrosquei em um bug que não consigo sair. O meu programa, ao passar na linha `aux1=aux1->next;` simplesmente para de funcionar. Ele para de responder assim como acontece quando tu da um `scanf` sem usar `&` antes da variável. Alguém sabe me responder o por quê? Acho que é detalhe básico.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
int addin (lista *no1, lista *no2, lista *no3) {
long int soma;
soma=0;
nodeptr *aux1;
nodeptr *aux2;
aux1=no1->inicio->next;
aux2=no2->inicio->next;

while (aux1 != NULL || aux2 != NULL) {
    soma=soma+(aux1->info+aux2->info);
    printf ("Voltei aqui");
    printf ("\nValor do aux1->info: %d\n", aux1->info);
    printf ("\nValor do aux2->info: %d\n", aux2->info);
    printf ("\nValor da soma: %d\n", soma);
    insereElemento(no3, (soma%100000));
    if (soma/100000!=0) {
        soma=soma/100000;
    }
    aux1=aux1->next;

    printf ("Valor novo do aux1: %d", aux1->info);
    aux2=aux2->next;
    printf ("Valor novo do aux2: %d", aux2->info);
}
```

A declaração dos nós da lista são dados da seguinte forma:

```
typedef struct node {
    long int info;
    struct node *next;
} nodeptr;

typedef struct {
    nodeptr *inicio;
    nodeptr *fim;
} lista;
```

EDIT.: Função de inserção de elemento na lista

```
int insereElemento (lista *no, int elemento) {
nodeptr *novo = (nodeptr *) malloc (sizeof(nodeptr));
novo->info=elemento;

if (no->inicio==NULL) {
    inicializaLista(no);
} else {
    no->fim->next=novo;
    no->fim=novo;
    novo->next=NULL;
    printf ("\nElemento inserido com sucesso na lista: %d\n", no->fim->info);
}

}
```

Comment: Dei uma olhada superficial, e a condição do "while" está invertida, deveria usar "&&" ao invés de usar "||" como está agora.

Answer (score 0):

Teria que ver como foi iniciada a lista, o problema pode estar na inicialização dos valores.
E outra coisa, no começo do código os aux's não deveriam apontar apenas para o inicio?

Antes:

```
aux1=no1->inicio->next;
aux2=no2->inicio->next;
```

Mudança:

```
aux1=no1->inicio;
aux2=no2->inicio;
```

Comment: Não não. O trabalho pede para começar do segundo mesmo, o primeiro é -1. Vou editar para colocar a função de inserção no post.